# Ruby regexp doesn't work with double quote string?

Tags: ruby

```
regexp = /(?:status\\\":)(\d*)(?:\,)/
string = '\n{\"status\":80,\"message\":\"Test message\"}\n'
result = string.scan(regexp)[0]
puts result
```

Why does this work, but if I do

```
regexp = /(?:status\\\":)(\d*)(?:\,)/
string = "\n{\"status\":80,\"message\":\"Test message\"}\n"
result = string.scan(regexp)[0]
puts result
```

I get no results? The string I'm searching is copied from a Mechanize body result. I'm trying to use this same regexp on the direct result of a mechanize page object, and no matches are showing, I'm assuming for the same reason this issue is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `'\n'` and `"\n"` are not the same thing:

```
'\n'
#=> "\\n" literal-backslash n

"\n"
# => "\n" newline character
```

If you need the backslash codes to work, you need double-quoted strings.

Don't forget about things like `%q[...]` and `%Q[...]` as alternatives to using quotes if both types are used in your string and you don't want to escape them.

Comment: `'\"'` and `"\""` aren't the same things either.

Comment: My apologies, I'm still confused.. I would have thought that meant using single quotes would *not* work, and double quotes *would* work.

For example, here is the Rubular link to what I'm doing... how do I correct my search to work with double quote strings? http://rubular.com/r/fCwpv8BKXD

Comment: I did some more research: if I use p instead of puts on my mechanize page.body, terminal shows:
    `"\n{\"status\":1,\"message\":\"status_ok\",\"new_account\":true}\n"`

If I use p on my double quoted string, it shows the same thing. If I use p on my single quoted string, it shows the string but with two sets of \ per escaped character. But again - I would think that means double quotes *would* match and single quotes would have the issue. But it's the other way around!

Comment: The point I'm trying to make here is if you have sequences like `\n` in your string, you *probably* need to use double quotes for it. I'm not sure why you're using single quotes other than habit, but it's inappropriate here. You need to match your regular expression and string. Note that your single-quoted string will match only because you have `status\\\"` when really all you should have is `status\"`. As others have observed, just use `JSON.parse` to avoid all of this, presuming you have a correctly formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use JSON for that:

```
JSON.parse(string)['status']
#=> 80
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you. I'm still confused on why I was having the original issue though...

Comment: You're just missing a basic understanding of ruby strings, regexes, what needs to be escaped when and where. I would start with the documentation for `String` and `Regex`

Comment: The thing is, I've been researching this for hours and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've never had issues with escaping things before. What is the appropriate form of my regexp that will match properly with  `string = "\n{\"status\":80,\"message\":\"Test message\"}\n"`? `/(?:status\\\":)(\d*)(?:\,)/` only works for the single quote form.

Comment: You're probably looking for: `string[/(?<=status":)\d+/]` but you should really use JSON. Read the lookbehind section on the Regexp page for info.